# Monitor request: obtain post data, headers, response

Tags: crossrider

I have been developing `crossrider` extension. I need to obtain data about users requests and then analyse them. For that, I used `appAPI.webRequest.monitor.onRequest` method.
However I am not able to obtain some information that I would really need:

- **If request is POST, I am not able to get post parameters (data)**
- I am not able to get response headers and response text

@Shlomo already proposed solution to use `appAPI.request` method to obtain response text and headers, but you can not do that for post requests if you dont have post parameters (data). Also that way, every request is made twice, which is not desired.

Comment: Currently, the appAPI.webRequest.monitor.onRequest.addListener method returns the following items: tabId,pageUrl,iframeUrl,requestUrl,requestMethod. Therefore, the callback cannot obtain the POST **data** or headers. Nevertheless, I have added a request for then to the wish list of new features for the product team to consider, subject to it being feasible cross browser. Of course the response is never going to be available at the time of request and as previously suggested, you can obtain it by making the request yourself using appAPI.request. [**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]